# Nancy Rendering Embedded views with .Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, nancy, .net-core, project.json

I've jumped many hurdles, but alas I still see the default 404 iamge rendered by Nancy.
I've 'mastered' `project.json` so I can embed my assets (including /assets/views/index.html), using the following block in the `project.json` file:

```
 "buildOptions": {
  "embed": [
    "assets/**",
    "Content/**",
    "fonts/**",
    "Scripts/bootstrap.js",
    "Scripts/jquery-2.2.2.js",
    "Scripts/mustache.js",
    "favicon.ico"

    //, "Scripts/**" - include this and build fails with errors in *.targets (!)
  ]
}
```

This is confirmed when debugging and querying assembly resources. All good.

My Bootstapper contains:

```
        protected override void ConfigureApplicationContainer(TinyIoCContainer container)
    {
        DependencyResolver.ConfigureDependencies(container);
        ResourceViewLocationProvider
            .RootNamespaces
            .Add(GetAssembly(), "<name to assembly>");  //embedded resource directory location
    }
```

And yet in my IndexModule:

```
    public class IndexModule : NancyModule
{
    public IndexModule() 
    {
        Get("/", args => Response.AsFile("assets/views/index.html", "text/html"));
    }
}
```

This renders nothing... could I be missing anything ? It was working fine with .Net Framework

Comment: Why are you using the AsFile extension and not the AsHtml?